# Android save Image from url and then retrieve it

Tags: java, android

I need to save an image from an Url provided by a webservice and then in some Activities I need to retrieve and use that image.

Since I was already using Picasso in order to download and cache images I've used the following method:

```
public void downloadFile(String url) {
        Picasso.with(AnimationActivity.this).load( url).into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                try {
                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    File myDir = new File(root + "/bBackground");
                    if (!myDir.exists()) {
                        myDir.mkdirs();
                    }
                    String name = "bBg.jpg";
                    myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();                        
                    } catch(Exception e){}
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}
            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
        });

    }
```

And then in order to retrieve the image I've tried with the following code:

```
String bgImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/bBackground/bBg.jpg";
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap mustOpen = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bgImagePath, options);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bBgImage);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mustOpen);
```

But I get an error when retrieving the image:

```
E/BitmapFactory(30761): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/bBackground/bBg.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a problem related to the saving or retrieving method?

Comment: Have you checked whether the callback for the url you are giving is coming back to `onBitmapLoaded` method

Comment: Log your swallowed exception and post the logcat (if any)

Comment: @fractalwrench it doesn't return any exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added following permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To save image use following function:

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/bBackground");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
 }
File image = new File(dir, "/bBg.jpg");

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(image);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();    
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found. Did you" +
            " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the   manifest?");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }   
}
```

To read this image you can use:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(){
  File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
  File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/bBackground");
  File image = new File(dir, "/bBg.jpg");

  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
  Bitmap mustOpen = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image, options);

  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bofrostBgImage);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(mustOpen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  code this issue is with picasso target.

```
private Target loadtarget;

    public void loadBitmap(String url) {

        if (loadtarget == null)
            loadtarget = new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap,
                        Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    // do something with the Bitmap
                    handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };

        Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(loadtarget);
    }

    public void handleLoadedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // do something here
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/bBackground");
            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                myDir.mkdirs();
            }
            String name = "bBg.jpg";
            myDir = new File(myDir, name);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String bgImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/bBackground/bBg.jpg";
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap mustOpen = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bgImagePath, options);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mustOpen);
    }
```